# SSH in Bash Script Messing Up File Read

Tags: bash, unix

I have a script that reads a file line by line and does stuff based on what it reads. One of the things it does is ssh to a remote server and gets some information. For some reason that's completely beyond me, this stops the reading of lines from the file.

The script is essentially (I've cut out a lot of it to simplify the question, so don't worry if it looks like it doesn't really do anything):

```
cat $csv | while read line; do
   shopt -s nocasematch
   for j in "${file_list[@]}"; do
      found=0;
      for i in $(ssh some_server "ls /some_path/${line:0:1}/${line:1:1}/$line*"); do
         if [[ $i =~ .*$j$ ]]; then
            echo "do something";
            found=1;
            break;
         fi;
      done;
      if [[ $found -ne 1 ]]; then
         echo "don't have $j";
      fi;
      if [[ $found -ne 1 && $j == '\.pdf' ]]; then
         getPDF $line ${dest};
      fi;
   done;
   shopt -u nocasematch
done
```

This script winds up only running on the first line of the csv. If I replace the "ssh" part of the script with anything else though, it runs all the way through on all lines of the file. What gives?

Comment: Is ssh eating your stdin (here, your [useless use of cat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat) is stdin) ?  Try ssh -n and see what happens ...

Comment: I strongly recommend you always use `read -r` when doing line by line reading of a file, and you probably want `while IFS=$'\n' read -r` at that if whitespace is important to you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ssh` is consuming stdin. Pass `-n`.

Comment: That did it. Thanks! For those of you looking at this in the future who want more explanation, look up the -n option by running "man ssh." The final working version of the script is the same as above, except that the ssh part reads "ssh -n some_server..."

Answer (score 0):

If you run commands which read from stdin (such as `ssh`) inside a loop, you need to ensure that either:

- Your loop isn't iterating over stdin
- Your command has had its stdin redirected:

The former:

```
while read -u 5 -r; do
  ssh "$REPLY" ...
done 5<file
```

...which, using bash 4.1 or newer, can be rewritten with automatic file descriptor assignment as so:

```
while read -u "$file_fd" -r; do
  ssh "$REPLY" ...
done {file_fd}<file
```

The latter:

```
while read -r; do
  ssh "$REPLY" ... </dev/null
done <file
```