# while loop to read file ends prematurely

Tags: bash, ssh, while-loop

The eventual goal is to have my bash script execute a command on multiple servers.  I almost have it set up.  My SSH authentication is working, but this simple while loop is killing me.  When I execute the while loop, reading my file for host names, it works fine when I run a

> ssh $HOST "uname -a"

but when I attempt to run another ssh command,

> ssh $HOST "oslevel -s"

the while loop ends early!  I can't figure it out.  **Why would the while read do loop run perfectly fine with the first command, but not when the second is added?**

I have a simple text file called hosts.list that has 4 hostnames, one per line.

```
    $ cat hosts.list
    pcced1bip04
    pcced1bit04
    pcced1bo02
    pcced1bo04

    $ cat getinfo.bash
    #!/bin/bash
    set -x
    while read HOST
      do
        echo $HOST
        ssh $HOST "uname -a"
        #ssh $HOST "oslevel -s"
        echo ""
      done  < hosts.list`
```

When it runs, it works fine.  It goes through the file, line by line and gets the results of `"uname -a"`.  So everything is fine, right? (Sorry, but I turned on `set -x`).

```
    $ ./getinfo.bash
    + read HOST
    + echo pcced1bip04
    pcced1bip04
    + ssh pcced1bip04 'uname -a'
    AIX pcced1bip04 1 6 0001431BD400
    + echo ''

    + read HOST
    + echo pcced1bit04
    pcced1bit04
    + ssh pcced1bit04 'uname -a'
    AIX pcced1bit04 1 6 0001431BD400
    + echo ''

    + read HOST
    + echo pcced1bo02
    pcced1bo02
    + ssh pcced1bo02 'uname -a'
    AIX pcced1bo02 1 6 0009FE2AD400
    + echo ''

    + read HOST
    + echo pcced1bo04
    pcced1bo04
    + ssh pcced1bo04 'uname -a'
    AIX pcced1bo04 1 6 0009FE2AD400
    + echo ''

    + read HOST
    $
```

**The problem occurs when I enable the line** [ssh $HOST "oslevel -s"].  When I do, the script only reads the first line of the file, and then stops.  **Why won't it go onto the other lines?**

```
    $ ./getinfo.bash
    + read HOST
    + echo pcced1bip04
    pcced1bip04
    + ssh pcced1bip04 'uname -a'
    AIX pcced1bip04 1 6 0001431BD400
    + ssh pcced1bip04 'oslevel -s'
    6100-06-02-1044
    + echo ''

    + read HOST
    $
```

If I had a problem with my script, why would it be working perfectly fine with just the `[ssh $HOST "uname -a"]` in the while loop?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSH in Bash Script Messing Up File Read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585100/ssh-in-bash-script-messing-up-file-read)

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams There's another solution besides that. Also, if the user somehow wants to interact with `ssh` that can't be used.

Comment: @konsolebox That's arguably a reason to write a better answer to that other question, rather than splitting focus. (Yes, I'm answering here -- but I'm *also* voting to close).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm not sure about that. The question's title here is more descriptive than the other. One asking for something he can't find easily could be a proof for that.

Comment: @konsolebox, granted, but that's why close-as-duplicate establishes a pointer as part of the knowledgebase.

Comment: Aren't closed threads in the risk of being permanently closed? i.e. permanently deleted from public view. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 5):

If you run commands which read from stdin (such as `ssh`) inside a loop, you need to ensure that either:

- Your loop isn't iterating over stdin
- Your command has had its stdin redirected:

...otherwise, the command can consume input intended for the loop, causing it to end.

The former:

```
while read -u 5 -r hostname; do
  ssh "$hostname" ...
done 5<file
```

...which, using bash 4.1 or newer, can be rewritten with automatic file descriptor assignment as so:

```
while read -u "$file_fd" -r hostname; do
  ssh "$hostname" ...
done {file_fd}<file
```

The latter:

```
while read -r hostname; do
  ssh "$hostname" ... </dev/null
done <file
```

...can also, for ssh alone, can also be approximated with the `-n` parameter (which also redirects stdin from `/dev/null`):

```
while read -r hostname; do
  ssh -n "$hostname"
done <file
```

Comment: (To read more about automatic file descriptor assignment, see the second paragraph under `REDIRECTION` in the bash manpage.)

Answer (score 2):

Assign to an array before the loop, so that you are not using stdin for your loop variables. The `ssh` inside  the loop can then use stdin without interfering with your loop.

```
readarray a <  hosts.list
for HOST in "${a[@]}"; do 
       ssh $HOST "uname -a"
       #...other stuff in loop
done
```

Answer (score 1):

As the solution specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585100/ssh-in-bash-script-messing-up-file-read) use `-n` option for `ssh` or open file with a different handle:

```
while read -u 4 HOST
  do
    echo $HOST
    ssh $HOST "uname -a"
    ssh $HOST "oslevel -s"
    echo ""
  done 4< hosts.list`
```

Answer (score -1):

maybe with python XD

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import Queue
from subprocess import call

logfile = sys.argv[1]
q = Queue.Queue()

with open(logfile) as data:
    datalines = (line.rstrip('\r\n') for line in data)
    for line in datalines:
        q.put(line)


while not q.empty() :
    host = q.get()
    print "++++++ " + host + " ++++++"
    call(["ssh", host, "uname -a"])
    call(["ssh", host, "oslevel -s"])
    print "++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
```

Comment: Incidentally -- if you were reading the list from `sys.stdin`, as the parent's shell script does, your Python program here would have the exact same problem. So it's not rewriting in Python as such that fixes the problem, it's allocating a separate fd rather than reusing stdin (which `open()` does out-of-the-box).

Comment: :/ i ran this script wiyh no errors, aand a host list with 10 hosts

Comment: Quite right, it'll work -- but it's not that it works because it's Python, it's that it works because it's not reusing FD 0 for the open call.