# Bash looping through file ends prematurely

Tags: bash, while-loop

I have troubles in Bash looping within a text file of ~20k lines.

Here is my (minimised) code:

```
LINE_NB=0
while IFS= read -r LINE; do
    LINE_NB=$((LINE_NB+1))
    CMD=$(sed "s/\([^ ]*\) .*/\1/" <<< ${LINE})
    echo "[${LINE_NB}] ${LINE}: CMD='${CMD}'"   
done <"${FILE}"
```

The while loop ends prematurely after a few hundreds iterations. However, the loop works correctly if I remove the CMD=$(sed...) part. So, evidently, there is some interference I cannot spot.

As I ready [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18753229/while-loop-to-read-file-ends-prematurely), I also tried:

```
LINE_NB=0
while IFS= read -r -u4 LINE; do
    LINE_NB=$((LINE_NB+1))
    CMD=$(sed "s/\([^ ]*\) .*/\1/" <<< ${LINE})
    echo "[${LINE_NB}] ${LINE}: CMD='${CMD}'"
done 4<"${FILE}"
```

but nothing changes. Any explanation for this behaviour and help on how can I solve it?

Thanks!

To clarify the situation for user1934428 (thanks for your interest!), I now have created a minimal script and added "set -x". The full script is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -x
FILE="$1"
LINE_NB=0

while IFS= read -u "$file_fd" -r LINE; do
  LINE_NB=$((LINE_NB+1))
  CMD=$(sed "s/\([^ ]*\) .*/\1/" <<< "${LINE}")
  echo "[${LINE_NB}] ${LINE}: CMD='${CMD}'" #, TIME='${TIME}' "

done {file_fd}<"${FILE}"

echo "Done."
```

The input file is a list of ~20k lines of the form:

```
S1 0.018206
L1 0.018966
F1 0.006833
S2 0.004212
L2 0.008005
I8R190 18.3791
I4R349 18.5935
...
```

The while loops ends prematurely at (seemingly) random points. One possible output is:

```
+ FILE=20k/ir-collapsed.txt
+ LINE_NB=0
+ IFS=
+ read -u 10 -r LINE
+ LINE_NB=1
++ sed 's/\([^ ]*\) .*/\1/'
+ CMD=S1
+ echo '[1] S1 0.018206: CMD='\''S1'\'''
[1] S1 0.018206: CMD='S1'
+ echo '[6510] S1514 0.185504: CMD='\''S1514'\'''
...[snip]...
[6510] S1514 0.185504: CMD='S1514'
+ IFS=
+ read -u 10 -r LINE
+ echo Done.
Done.
```

As you can see, the loop ends prematurely after line 6510, while the input file is ~20k lines long.

Comment: Does it always abort at the same point for a given `FILE`, and without error message? Does tracing it with `set -x` reveal any insight? Is this the **complete** script, or did you do any settings before (for instance, a `set -e`)?

Comment: It actually aborts are varying points. I commented out everything else in my script, and the issue persists. There is no "set -e". Adding set -x, it shows:

+ FILE=....
+ LINE_NB=0
+ IFS=
[snip]
...
+ IFS=
+ read -u 10 -r LINE
+ LINE_NB=662
++ sed 's/\([^ ]*\) .*/\1/'
+ CMD=S152
+ echo '[662] S152 0.183399: CMD='\''S152'\'''
[662] S152 0.183399: CMD='S152'
+ IFS=
+ read -u 10 -r LINE
+ echo Done.
Done.

Comment: Do you by chance have set an `ulimit` on the maximum execution time of a program? Otherwise, I would - for debugging - replace the `sed` by some simple program (such as `:`), to see whether `sed` is the culprit or something else.

Comment: And, you forgot to quote the variable in the input redirection: `<<< ${LINE}` should be `<<< "${LINE}"`. Of course, if this were the reason, you would abort at the same line always, and get an error message.

Comment: Running `sed` on individual lines is a bad antipattern anyway. You are reinventing `awk '{printf "[%i] %s: CMD=\047%s\047\n", NR, $0, $1}' "$FILE"` with broken quoting.

Comment: I posted a minimal script and output. Unfortunately I am quite scared of awk, I know I should learn it someday... ;)   I certainly could try with awk, but actually my real script needs to perform a match of $0 against several regexps and, depending on the result, append something to one of several files (now I use if ...=~ elif ... fi).

Comment: I think I found my issue. First, I replaced "sed" on individual lines with: ```IFS=' ' read -r -a TOK <<< "${LINE}"; CMD="${TOK[0]}"; TIME="${TOK[1]}"```. This of course resulted in higher efficiency (and saved me from learning awk, at least for now ;)). The problem still persisted. I added "wc -l "${FILE}" to the end of the script and noticed that also "wc" failed. A reason could be that ${FILE} is still growing (it is appended by another running process). By copying "${FILE}" into a new file (ie, freezing it as far as the script is concerned), the loop works. Strange behaviour though...

Comment: a pluse-uno for updating your Q per reader requests! Any chance there is a `&` that is being interpreted to launch a background process ? Good luck.

Comment: Maybe update Q one more to show the expected output from that sample input. 2-3 lines is enough. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, making a stable file copy is a best start.
Learning `awk` and/or `perl` is still well worth your time. It's not as hard as it looks. :)

Aside from that, a couple of optimizations - try to never run any program inside a loop when you can avoid it. For a 20k line file, that's 20k `sed`s, which really adds up unnecessarily. Instead you could just use parameter parsing for this one.

```
# don't use all caps.
# cmd=$(sed "s/\([^ ]*\) .*/\1/" <<< "${line}") becomes
cmd="${cmd%% *}" # strip everything from the first space
```

Using the `read` to handle that is even better, since you were already using it anyway, but don't spawn another if you can avoid it. As much as I love it, `read` is pretty inefficient; it has to do a lot of fiddling to handle all its options.

```
while IFS= read -u "$file_fd" cmd timeval; do
  echo "[$((++line_nb))] CMD='${CMD}' TIME='${timeval}'"
done {file_fd}<"${file}"
```

or

```
while IFS= read -u "$file_fd" -r -a tok; do
  echo "[$((++line_nb))] LINE='${tok[@]}' CMD='${tok[0]}' TIME='${tok[1]}'"
done {file_fd}<"${file}"
```

(This will *sort* of rebuild the line, but if there were tabs or extra spaces, etc, it will only pad with the 1st char of `$IFS`, which is a space by default. Shouldn't matter here.)

`awk` would have made short work of this, though, and been a lot faster, with better tools already built in.

```
awk '{printf "NR=[%d] LINE=[%s] CMD=[%s] TIME=[%s]\n",NR,$0,$1,$2 }' 20k/ir-collapsed.txt
```

Run some time comparisons - with and without the `sed`, with one `read` vs two, and then compare each against the `awk`. :)

The more things you have to do with each line, and the more lines there are in the file, the more it will matter. Make it a habit to do even small things as neatly as you can - it will pay off well in the long run.

Comment: That's very cool! I didn't know about the possibility of doing ```read -u "$file_fd" cmd timeval```. As for awk, I see that I really have to learn it! Thanks!